# Can't import Cloud Firestore to Stripe customer account

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm trying to import Cloud Firestore `users` data to Stripe customer accounts. Stripe does work but it doesn't work when it creates customer. No error code. Just skipped.

The code:

```js
import firebase from "../config/firebase";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxx");
console.log("stripe", stripe);
// successfully get
async componentDidMount() {
  await db.collection("users")
    .get()
    .then((snap) => {
      let promises = [];
      snap.forEach(async (doc) => {
        console.log('doc id", doc.id);
        // successfully get      

        const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
          name: doc.data().name,
          email: doc.data().email,
        });
        console.log("stripeCS", stripeCustomer.id);
        // not working :(

      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
}
```

I have added `async await` then it shows `Promise{<pending>}`.

Answer (score 1):

I could have done the below:

```js
db.collection("users")
  .get()
  .then((snap) => {
    let promises = [];
    snap.forEach(async (doc) => {
      console.log("doc", doc.data());
      await stripe.customers.create({
        name: doc.data().name,
        email: doc.data().email,
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then((hoge) => {
    console.log("ends");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`err: ${err}`);
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean that the code in this answer solved your issue?